# ActiveRecord query filtering nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have the following models

```
Course has_many :students
Course has_many :lectures
Lecture has_many :topics
```

If I do:

```
courses = Course.find(:all, :includes => [:students, {:lectures => :topics}])
```

I get all courses, students,lectures, and topics.

I want to get only courses that have certain students in them and then for each of those courses only want to get certain lectures back but all topics for each of those lectures.

So say I want to get all courses with a student named 'John' but only the 2 most recent lectures for each of those courses and all of the topics for those 2 lectures.

I don't understand how to apply these filters to the original query above.

Would love some guidance on how to perform queries like these.

Comment: I recommend using the gem "squeel" (https://github.com/ernie/squeel). It has much more "intuitive" syntax and you can find the documentation you're looking for in github

Comment: What field are you looking at to determine if a lecture is 'recent'?

Comment: And what database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the query API to modify what is eager loaded:

```
courses = Course.includes(:students, {:lectures => :topics}).
                 where(:students => {:name => 'John'})
```

Getting just the 2 most recent lectures for each course is a major challenge, I don't believe there is a cross-database solution that will do this without a recursive subquery to determine the rank (which would be a major performance drain for non-trivial amounts of data and cancel any benefit of eager loading).  You can possibly determine the most recent (MAX), and then the next most recent after that (MAX that are earlier than the original MAX), but this approach will also be quite inefficient and very messy.

If you can pick a specific DBMS, this might be doable.  Alternatively, pick a different strategy to determine 'recent' (e.g. a cached date on each Course, or a fixed amount of time passed).

**UPDATE**

Assuming you are fine with just eager loading all lectures and manually selecting the top 2, you could do this (for JSON) using the [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) serializer:

```
courses = ... # same as above
courses.each do |c|
  c.lectures = c.lectures.sort_by(&:happens_at)[-1..-2]
end.as_json(:include => [:students, {:lectures => {:include => :topics}}])
```

Comment: Thanks, if I was doing this query to return a JSON blob how would I build it up with the most recent lectures.
[`code`]
courses = Course.where(:students => {:name => 'John'})
courses.each do |course|
   course[:most_recent] = course.lectures.order(:happens_at).first
   course[:next_recent] = course.lectures.order(:happens_at)[1]
end
[/`code`]
seems awkward though